# how to count and mark its boudary of similar objects in a image?

Tags: computer-vision

how to identify the similar objects in a image? Consider a single image. In this three similar fuses are there. Two similar indicators are there. 
I applied MSER algorithm which give stable regions (green ellipse). Then I applied SURF algorithm to detect the descriptors in the MSER stable regions.

how to match the descriptors to identify the  three fuses?
how to match the descriptors to identify the  two  indicators?

please help me in this regard!